# Usage of "conversely" when proving something is the smallest subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

In at least two places in *Linear Algebra Done Right* ("sum of subspaces is the smallest containing subspace" and "span is the smallest containing subspace"), Axler has propositions of the form "$U$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ such that $P(U)$".

The proofs go like this:

- First paragraph: He shows that $U$ is a subspace of $V$.
- Second paragraph: He shows that $P(U)$. Then he says "conversely" and shows that if $W$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $P(W)$, then $U \subseteq W$.

My confusion is that I don't see how there is a converse in this proof. To show that $X$ is the smallest set in $\mathcal C$, my understanding is that we need to show:

1. $X \in \mathcal C$. Above, this corresponds to showing $U$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $P(U)$.
2. If $Y \in \mathcal C$ then $X\subseteq Y$. Above, this corresponds to showing that if $W$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $P(W)$, then $U \subseteq W$.

So logically, we are showing a conjunction of two statements, of which one of the statements is a one-sided implication. There is no converse as far as I can tell.

Axler is proving all the same things, but note the difference in division of the parts: he shows $P(U)$ as part of the second paragraph, whereas I grouped it as part of the first paragraph.

Comment: Now, mathematicians are supposed to be nitpicky. But not usually about writing style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that I have used the word "conversely" correctly. To prove that two sets $D$ and $E$ are equal, one often proves that $D \subset E$ and $E \subset D$. The statement that $D \subset E$ is equivalent to the following statement:
$$ \text{If $x \in D$, then $x \in E$.}$$
The converse of the statement above is:
$$ \text{If $x \in E$, then $x \in D$.}$$
The statement above is of course equivalent to the statement that $E \subset D$. Thus when I have shown that $D \subset E$ and write "conversely", this means that I am about to prove the last statement displayed above.